# Wordpress commenting system with Facebook/Open ID/Twitter login?

Tags: php, wordpress, social-networking, single-sign-on

Is there any Wordpress commenting system with Facebook/Open ID/Twitter login?
I know Disqus or Intense Debate but I don't like them because the comments aren't hosted on my server. I want full control.
I can find plugins for Facebook and Twitter separately, but not together.
Is there any way to do what Intense Debate can do without a 3rd party hosting involved?

Comment: Disqus will give you nearly full control. Check out their moderation tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I use a combination of both twitter and facebook plugins that work in harmony on my site, they are made by the same developer.</strike>

[Simple Twitter Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/)

[Simple Facebook Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/)

<strike>You can see them working in tandem [on my blog](http://jondavidjohn.com).</strike>

<strike>(No longer using WordPress)</strike>

**Back to using wordpress!**

This does what you want and more, pretty slick.

[Social Plugin for Wordpress](http://mailchimp.com/social-plugin-for-wordpress/)